# Create kite diagram in R

Tags: r

I have been trying unsuccessfully to create a kite chart. I would like to show the total number of each fish species (a-f) that were observed at each depth level (820, 1208, 1750 and 2209 m). I have tried `kiteChart` in `plotrix`, but cannot work out how to get my data into the correct format for it to work. 
I have tried to follow another post in a forum using the following, but it did not work:

```
X <- read.table(textConnection("Species Total Depth
A 6 820 
A 15 1208 
A 77 1750 
A 41 2209 
B 11 820 
B 17 1208 
B 17 1750 
B 1 2209 
C 0 820 
C 13 1208 
C 5 1750 
C 4 2209 
D 32 820 
D 0 1208 
D 0 1750 
D 0 2209 
E 0 820 
E 11 1208 
E 0 1750 
E 0 2209 
F 0 820 
F 0 1208 
F 0 1750 
F 6 2209"),header=TRUE) 
library(reshape) 
X2 <- recast(X,Depth~Species,id.var=1:2) 
X3 <- as.matrix(X2[,-1]) 
rownames(X3) <- X2$Depth 
colnames(X3) <- names(X2)[-1] 
library(plotrix) 
kiteChart(t(X3),xlab="Depth",ylab="Species") 

#or 
 x2<-matrix(X$Total,ncol=3) 
rownames(x2)<-unique(X$Distance) 
colnames(x2)<-unique(X$Species) 
kiteChart(t(X3),xlab="Distance",ylab="Species")
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?
Many thanks

UPDATE: I have re-arranged my data and can now produce the following plot.

```
X <- read.table(textConnection("Species Depth Total 
A 820 6 
A 1208 15 
A 1750 77 
A 2209 41 
B 820 11 
B 1208 17 
B 1750 17 
B 2209 1 
C 820 0 
C 1208 13 
C 1750 5 
C 2209 4 
D 820 32 
D 1208 0 
D 1750 0 
D 2209 0 
E 820  0
E 1208 11 
E 1750 0 
E 2209 0 
F 820 0 
F 1208 0 
F 1750 0 
F 2209 6"),header=TRUE) 
library(reshape) 
X2 <- recast(X,Depth~Species,id.var=1:2) 
X3 <- as.matrix(X2[,-1]) 
rownames(X3) <- X2$Depth 
colnames(X3) <- names(X2)[-1] 
library(plotrix) 
kiteChart(t(X3),xlab="Depth",ylab="Species")
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if `kiteChart` can have a continuous 'time axis' (depth in your case), where x-values possibly are irregularly spaced. A simple example: two species at three times/depths `m <- matrix(sample(1:6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)`; `kiteChart(m)`. Then imagine that they were sampled not at 1, 2, 3 meters, but on 1, 3, 9 meters. Try `timepos` argument: `kiteChart(m, timepos = c(1, 3, 9))`. Seems like the scale on the x-axis is categorical, not continuous. Please correct me if I have misunderstood something about `kiteChart`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
library(plotrix)
x2<-matrix(X$Total,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(x2)<-unique(X$Depth) 
rownames(x2)<-unique(X$Species)
kiteChart(x2,xlab="Depth",ylab="Species")
```

It produces the following chart on my installation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that the the 'time axis' in `kiteChart` seems to be discrete and not continuous (see small example in my comment above), I was thinking of an alternative way to visualize your data. What about an area plot, which will give you the depths on a continuous scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = X, aes(x = Depth, y  = Total, fill = Species)) +
  geom_area(position = "stack") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I like this plot. It shows the relative total abundance of fish at each of the depths, as well as the abundance of each species to that total. Thank you for that